# Testing JSON string response with Nunit

Tags: .net, json, unit-testing, nunit

I have a method that returns a JSON string (I've hard-coded in the values for the time being). I am trying to unit test this but am struggling to work out how best to do so.

```
    [HttpGet, Route("GetData")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetData()
    {
        var person = new Person();
        person.Name = "Ben";
        person.Age = 30;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        return json; 
    }
```

So far I have tried the following (started off with):

```
  [Test]
        public void GetData_ApiCallMade_ReturnsJsonString()
        {
            var controller = new Controller();
            JsonResult result = controller.GetData() as JsonResult;

        }
```

(This errors as it cannot convert a string to a `JsonResult`)

I can get a passing test with:

```
 [Test]
        public void GetData_ApiCallMade_ReturnsJsonString()
        {
            var controller= new Controller();
            var result = controller.GetData();
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);

        }
```

However this doesn't really seem to test anything substantial.

I'm new to this and would appreciate any help - I've looked around at other questions/answers but still cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can use a 3rd party library, to covert to json, like Newtonsoft for example :)

Comment: In my test too? @Hackerman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the string response containing your object serialized to JSON, you could use the same library to deserialize the object to the same class.

```
var result = controller.GetData();
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(result.Value);
```

Now you can test if the object you got from your controller is valid. Simply assert the eqality of its properties to their expected values.

```
Assert.AreEqual(person.Name, "Bob");
Assert.AreEqual(person.Age, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Controller actions should return the appropriate strongly typed responses

For example

```
[HttpGet("GetData")]
public ActionResult<Person> GetData() {
    var person = new Person() {
        Name = "Ben",
        Age = 30
    };

    //...other logic may return an error result.

    return person; //Return action result
}
```

The framework request pipeline will serialize and return the response based on the request.

It can easily unit tested

```
[Test]
public void GetData_ApiCallMade_Returns_Person() {
    //Arrange
    var controller = new Controller();
    //...also set expectations

    //Act
    var result = controller.GetData();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Person person = result.Value as Person;
    //...other assertions.

}
```

#### Reference [Test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing)

In order to review the expected JSON is returned when actually called, then An integration test that actually makes a HTTP request should be done.

```
//Arrange
//...code removed for brevity

//Act
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

//Assert
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
Assert.AreEqual(person.Name, "Bob");
Assert.AreEqual(person.Age, 30);
```

#### Reference [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests)